# How does newly elected leader apply entries in raft?

Tags: replication, distributed-system, consensus, raft

Let's say you have 3 servers `S1`, `S2` and `S3`. `S1` (leader), replicates a log to `S2` and `S3` and then applies the log respond to the client and crashes. So we have

```
S1   1
S2   1
S3   1
```

Now when `S2` becomes the leader (with the vote from `S3`) how will it apply the log? According to the Raft paper

```
If there exists an N such that N > commitIndex, a majority
of matchIndex[i] ≥ N, and log[N].term == currentTerm:
set commitIndex = N.
```

In the above case, the term of `S2` (`commitIndex` = 0) would be 2 while the term of the log would always be 1; hence, the last condition would not be satisfied? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Every node has an event log with two core pointers: the committed events and the uncommitted events. The point of raft the protocol is to replicate *both* of these pointers across the system.

```
| 0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7 8 9 |
          ^             ^
  Committed   Uncommitted
```

Every replication message a Follower receives from the Leader updates both of these pointers. The message has events to append to the log (updating the `uncommitted` pointer). It also has an index to update the `committed` pointer.

When a Follower receives this message and updates its `committed` pointer then it **applies** all the events that just moved from *uncommitted* to *committed*.

The `committed` pointer sent to the Followers is a copy of what the Leader has on its log. The Leader updates its `committed` pointer when it receives a quorum from the Followers, and **applies** all the events that moved from *uncommitted* to *committed*.

A **newly-elected Leader** first needs to ensure that its version of the log is replicated to the Followers, and as the new Leader receives quorum from the Followers it updates its `committed` pointer, replicates that pointer back to the Followers, and applies the events as above.

Comment: As described in raft paper we maintain lastApplied and commitIndex but in the scenario described above when S1 (the first leader) dies it has state like 

S1(logs:[1], commitIndex: 1, lastApplied: 1) whille s2 and s3 have

S2(logs:[1], commitIndex: 0, lastApplied: 0)
S3(logs:[1], commitIndex: 0, lastApplied: 0)

As the leader never commits the logs from older term these logs will never be committed.

Comment: Not true! If any node ever has a log value as committed then eventually all other nodes will see that value as committed. This is the very definition of the committed in consensus algorithms.

Comment: A log entry is committed once the leader that created the entry has replicated it on a majority of the servers. Hence once it's replicated leader commits it. I think the missing piece is,  which the paper mentions in section 8

The Leader Completeness
Property guarantees that a leader has all committed entries,
but at the start of its term, it may not know which
those are. To find out, it needs to commit an entry from
its term. Raft handles this by having each leader commit
a blank no-op entry into the log at the start of its
term.